# python AttributeError: module 'smtplib' has no attribute 'SMPT'

Tags: python, string, email, file-io

i am a python beginner and i'd like to get some help from you.
Recently i wrote a program which is about email spamming(retrieving data from a config file) using the 'smtp' module which i can't use very well so when i ran the program, it says this:

```
enter any key to exit
enter 'spam' to spam an email
Enter: spam
Running..Running..Running..Running..Running..Running..Running..Traceback  (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Leon\Desktop\Progetti\Gdaze\Gdaze.py", line 61, in <module>
emailSetupAndGo(getData()[0], getData()[1], getData()[2], getData()[3], getData()[4], getData()[5])
File "C:\Users\Leon\Desktop\Progetti\Gdaze\Gdaze.py", line 46, in emailSetupAndGo
server = smtplib.SMPT('smtp.gmail.com:587')
AttributeError: module 'smtplib' has no attribute 'SMPT'
```

After seeing this error i searched it and found out, on stackoverflow, a solution, but it worked just for people who named the file email.py.
Here you are the source code(I also think i made a mistake with the .split(' ') to delete the spaces) so you can tell me what the error is:

```
import smtplib
import sys

def getData():
    #GETTING DATA FROM THE FILE 
    configFile = open('config.txt', 'rt')
    usernameLine = configFile.readline()
    passwordLine = configFile.readline()
    nLine = configFile.readline()
    fromemailLine = configFile.readline()
    toemailLine = configFile.readline()
    msgLine = configFile.readline()
    configFile.close()
    if "<yourgmail's>" in usernameLine:
        sys.stderr.write("NoSettings ERROR: modify the config.txt file    before you run the program.")
    elif "<yourgmail's>" in passwordLine:
        sys.stderr.write("NoSettings ERROR: modify the config.txt file     before you run the program.")
    elif "<int>" in nLine:
        sys.stderr.write("NoSettings ERROR: modify the config.txt file     before you run the program.")
    elif "<youremail>" in fromemailLine:
        sys.stderr.write("NoSettings ERROR: modify the config.txt file     before you run the program.")
    elif "<emailtospam>" in toemailLine:
        sys.stderr.write("NoSettings ERROR: modify the config.txt file     before you run the program.")
    elif "<msg>" in msgLine:
        sys.stderr.write("NoSettings ERROR: modify the config.txt file     before you run the program.")
    else:
        sys.stdout.write("Running..")
        #DECLARING THE MAIN VARIABLES
        u = str(usernameLine[11:])
        pw = str(passwordLine[11:])
        n = str(nLine[27:])
        fromemail = str(fromemailLine[12:])
        toemail = str(toemailLine[10:])
        msg = str(msgLine[10:])
        #DELETING SPACES IN THE FILE TO STORE CORRECTLY THE DATA
        u.split(" ")
        pw.split(" ")
        n.split(" ")
        fromemail.split(" ")
        toemail.split(" ")
        msg.split(" ")
        data = [u, pw, n, fromemail, toemail, msg]
        return data

def emailSetupAndGo(n, username, password, fromemail, toemail, message):
    server = smtplib.SMPT('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    server.starttls()
    server.login(username, password)
    for i in n:
        server.sendmail(fromemail, toemail, message)
    server.quit()

def help():
    sys.stdout.write("enter any key to exit\nenter 'spam' to spam an email\n")

while True:
    help()
    entered = input("Enter: ")
    if entered == 'spam':
        getData()
        emailSetupAndGo(getData()[0], getData()[1], getData()[2], getData()[3], getData()[4], getData()[5])
    else:
        break
```

And here you are the config file:

```
username = <yourgmail's>
password = <yourgmail's>
number of emails to spam = <int> 
fromemail = <youremail>
toemail = <emailtospam>
message = <msg>
```

Comment: You wanted to import SMTP, not 'SMPT', right? Fix the typo, and things should be fine.

Comment: ..i'm gonna kill myself, what a dumb error, thank you ahahah

Comment: Believe it or not, this is actually a duplicate question (it happens all the time that people misspell it :P)